# Change title: mcmc_trace function with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used `mcmc_trace` function from the `bayesplot` package to plot traceplot with mcmc list, which is a ggplot item so it can be further edited by `ggplot` function.

Follows is the plot that produced by the function. I needed to change the title k[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEvSy.png)...k[20] to subject 1... subject 20. Are there any approaches I can achieve this with ggplot function?

[image]

Follows is a simple reproducible model.

```
library (r2jags)
library (bayesplot)
library (ggplot2)

# data
dlist <- list(
  NSubjects = 20,
  k = rep (5,20),
  n = rep (10,20)
)

# monitor
parameter <- 'theta'

# model
minimodel <- function(){
  for (i in 1:NSubjects){
    theta [i] ~ dbeta (1,1)
    k[i] ~ dbin(theta[i],n[i])
  }
}

samples <- jags(dlist, inits=NULL, parameter,
                model.file = minimodel,
                n.chains=1, n.iter=10, n.burnin=1, n.thin=1, DIC=T)

# mcmc list
codaSamples = as.mcmc.list(samples$BUGSoutput)

# select subjects
colstheta <- sprintf("theta[%d]",1:20)

# plot (here is where I need to change title, in this example: theta[1]...theta[20] to subject [1].. subject [20]
mcmc_trace(codaSamples[,colstheta]) +
  labs (x='Iteration',y='theta value',
        title='Traceplot - theta')
```

Comment: any chance of a [mcve] ... ???

Comment: @BenBolker Sorry! I have provided a reproducible example with a simple model in the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `colnames<-` to modify the column names. Since the object is a 1-element list containing a matrix-like object, you need to use `[[1]]`; if you have multiple chains you'll need to `lapply()` (or use a `for` loop) to apply the solution to every chain (i.e., every element in the list).

```r
cc <- codaSamples[,colstheta]
colnames(cc[[1]]) <- gsub("theta\\[([0-9]+)\\]","subject \\1",colnames(cc[[1]]))
mcmc_trace(cc, ...)
```

The code above finds the numerical element in each name and inserts it into the new name; since you happen to know in this case that these are elements 1:20, you could simplify considerably, e.g.

```
colnames(cc[[1]]) <- paste("subject",seq(ncol(cc[[1]])))
```